# How to create a Form UI by fetching JSON using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

So, I am kind of new to angularjs and want to learn on how can i generate a form ui from a external json for eg. currently i am using https://randomform.herokuapp.com

Every time i want to generate a new form using the json components and also how to submit the form on successful data entry.

I could fetch the object variables, but don't know how to create input elements using it.

```
// Angular JS Code
import angular from 'angular';
var app = angular.module('randomForm',[]);
//Getform controller

app.controller('getFormCtrl',function($scope ,$http, $log){

  //fetch response on click
 $scope.clickButton = function(){
   $http.get("https://randomform.herokuapp.com")
   .then(function(response){
       //storing the response
        $scope.form_dt = response;
        //log the response
        $log.info(response);

   },
  function(response){
  //Handles Error
   $scope.form = "Something Went Wrong";
 })}

});
```

And the html file :

```
<div class="container center" ng-controller="getFormCtrl">
            <!-- Form -->

     <button ng-click="clickButton()" class="btn">Get Form</button>


             <form class="myForm" ng-repeat="field in form_dt.data.data.form_fields">
                <h1>Form ID : {{form_dt.data.data.form_id}}</h1>
                <h1>Form Name : {{form_dt.data.data.form_name}}</h1>

              <div class="fields">   
                  <input type="field.component">
                       <h2> Label : {{field.label}}</h2>
                       <h2> Type :  {{field.component}} </h1>
                       <h2> Description : {{field.description}}</h2>
                       <h2> Editable : {{field.editable}}</h2>
                       <h2> Options : {{field.options}}</h2>
                       <h2> Required : {{field.required}}</h2>
                       <h2> Validation : {{field.validation}}</h2>
                       <h2> AutoSelect : {{field.autoselect}}</h2>
                       <h2> Autofill : {{field.autofill}}</h2> 
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit Form</button>
          </form>


  </div>
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build each input separately based on what the `component` value is. Here is a simple plunkr that does it for the `radio` component and the `textinput` component. You may have to hit "New form" a couple times as I only implemented two of the potential components. I would recommend using an `ng-switch` inside the `ng-repeat` for the fields, which would have the necessary logic to implement each `component` type.

```
<div ng-switch="field.component">
  <div ng-switch-when="radio">
    <div ng-repeat="option in field.options" class="radio">
      <label><input ng-model="field.value" name="$parent.$index" type="radio" value="{{option}}"/>{{option}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="textinput">
      <input class="form-control" ng-model="field.value" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- IMPLEMENT OTHER COMPONENT TYPES HERE -->
</div>
```

Note that you can't just set the `type` of the `input` to `field.component`, as you did above, because depending on the `component` type you'll need to structure things differently (e.g. a `textarea` element for the `textarea` component type or an `input` element for the `textinput` component type).

https://plnkr.co/edit/kRf9cuIVrTgGezKwvSFS

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a fairly complex piece of code. But I can give you a push in the right direction.

You will need an `ng-repeat` on your data. So say your data was in `$scope.formData` and I will use this set of random data taken from your website:

```
{
  "data": {
    "form_fields": [
      {
        "autofill": 70, 
        "component": "textinput", 
        "description": "enim totam aliquid suscipit et incididunt reiciendis", 
        "editable": false, 
        "label": "quam consectetur perspiciatis", 
        "required": true, 
        "validation": "^[0-9]+$"
      }, 
      {
        "component": "textarea", 
        "description": "nisi maiores ducimus fugiat sint pariaturat rerum cupidatat", 
        "editable": true, 
        "label": "voluptatum asperiores", 
        "required": false, 
        "validation": "^(.|\\n)+$"
      }
    ], 
    "form_id": "4Dwh0VTOfW41", 
    "form_name": "velit maxime qui"
  }, 
  "success": true
}
```

You would want your template to be something like this:

```
<div nr-repeat="field in formData.data.form_fields">
  <div ng-if="field.component = 'textinput'">
    <label>{{field.label}}
      <input type="text" {{field.required?'required':''}} pattern="{{field.validation}}" {{field.editable?'':'disabled'}} ...etc.../>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="field.component = 'textarea'">
    <label>{{field.label}}
      <textarea {{field.required?'required':''}} pattern="{{field.validation}}" {{field.editable?'':'disabled'}}></textarea>
    </label>
  </div>
  ... Put others here ...
</div>
```

Now this is far from complete and you will probably want to change the way some things work, but this should help get you started.